# OO class hierarchy

Tags: java, oop

recently got this interview question. "Please give the OO hierarchy of following classes. Bicycle, Car, Truck, Engine, and Wheel". Since no feedback is give, I don't know what should be the right answer. What do you guys think? And why? Many thanks.

Comment: what is your opinion for it ? :)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Personally I think a good book on OO would be jolly good.  Good luck

Comment: Clearly they are trying to see if you understand the difference between is-a and has-a.

Comment: Yes, agree. My answer is that Truck is Car. Car has engine and wheels. Bicycle is not related to Car's hierarchy, But Bicycle has wheels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know what should be the right answer.

There are various ways to model this.  Various "right" answers.  For example:

```
class VehiclePart

class Wheel extends VehiclePart

class Engine extends VehiclePart

class Vehicle {
  Wheel[] wheel
}

class PoweredVehicle extends Vehicle {
   Engine: engine
}

class Bicyle extends Vehicle 

class Car extends PoweredVehicle

class Truck extends PoweredVehicle
```

I'm using a textual notation I just made up for this answer.  If I has a whiteboard to hand, I would have drawn that as a UML class diagram ... or similar.

> And why

Because it adequately represents the classes and relationships.  Other models would or could too ... depending on the purpose of the model etcetera.

The point of the interview question was NOT to see if you could produce "the right answer", but to see if you had a basic grasp of OO modelling.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I see.. So I really should come up with a hierarchy and fit whose parts in, in that way a full OO modelling is shown.